# Angular Routing issue: Route parameter redirects to incorrect path

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-lazyloading

I'm facing an issue with Angular routing where I'm trying to navigate to a specific route that includes a route parameter, but it redirects me to a different path instead. I have a ToursComponent that displays a list of tour cards, and when I click on a "Get More" button for a specific tour, I want to navigate to the corresponding TourDetailsComponent with the tour's ID or title as a route parameter.

However, instead of navigating to /tours/:tourIdOrTitle, it redirects me to /home path. I have double-checked my routing configuration and ensured that the correct component is associated with the route, but the issue persists.

I have created a [repository on GitHub](https://github.com/leepaolo/routing-issue)

Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this routing problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think you have wrong routes configuration in `ToursRoutes`. Make `TOUR_DETAILS = ':tourIdOrTitle'` and let me know whether it worked

Comment: I made the changes and it gives me the correct path: http://localhost:4200/tours/0

The page it's empty. It supposed to render these: 

<div *ngIf="card">
  <h2>{{ card.titleHeader }}</h2>
 ...an more...
</div>

Comment: Yes, basically you had defined path that was `/tours` (in app.routes.ts) and then `tours/:id` in tours.routes.ts, so the path was `/tours/tours/:id`. The page is empty because that's the logic that you provided, but overall routing issue is resolved

Comment: May you help to fix the logic?

Comment: How **fix**? Your `tour-details` component template expects that `card` property is defined, define it inside `subscribe` I guess. There is no error or something, just no code that does anything